# Can't resolve 'react-hot-loader/webpack'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I've been stuck with this for a while trying to install and update. Finally, all the npm packages are in the latest version. Could you please let me know how I could get past this blocking error?

```
[ERROR] ERROR in multi react-hot-loader/patch event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.tsx
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-hot-loader/webpack' in '...'
     @ multi react-hot-loader/patch event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.tsx
```

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                {
                    test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: "url-loader"
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                    loader: "url-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

Here is the package.json so that the versions of the packages that I'm using are shown below:

```
    {
  "name": "MyProject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.2",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.6",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "4.1.0",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.27",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.2.7",
    "@types/react-table": "^6.7.11",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.1.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.11",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "style-loader": "0.21.0",
    "typescript": "2.9.2",
    "url-loader": "1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.12.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react-fontawesome": "^1.6.3",
    "ajv": "^6.5.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "get-latest": "^0.1.0",
    "latest-version": "^4.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.1.0",
    "npm-install-peers": "^1.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "update-all-packages": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to help you with this little information. Could you show your Webpack configuration perhaps?

Comment: @Tholle thanks for the suggestion, I've added the config file.

Comment: Have you [tried this](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/569#issuecomment-303833273)?

Comment: @Tholle Thank you, I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @Tholle I've added the package.json. Thank you.

Comment: @John, did you get answer? I am also looking for solution for same problem

Comment: @Mahesh I guess I had to update all packages to resolve this.